# Chunked request using XHR

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

Is there any way to use XMLHttpRequest to send a chunked request?

The use case is uploading streaming data to a server. I need to be able to upload binary data in smaller blocks, but I would prefer to avoid sending a full HTTP request for each block.

The HTTP 1.1 specification allows for chunked requests, but I have been unable to find any example in Javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any libraries that implement this off the top of my head, but you can use raw [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) and the progress callbacks. Keep in mind that chunked encoding will trigger browser repaints at uncontrollable intervals that change depending on the browser.

You might want to look at [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which are designed to handle this scenario in a much more user-friendly API.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that I can use the XHR callbacks to monitor a chunked response from the HTTP server, but I'm talking about sending the body of the initial request in small parts, as opposed to all at once.
I can fallback to WebSockets if XHR doesn't provide this functionality, but I'm curious to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Possible.

You can set `requestHeader "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xxxxxxxxxxxx"`, which contains the boundary, and construct a `Buffer`object with correct data.

Not all browsers support `Buffer`， so you should test first. In my case，Chrome and Firefox work well.